# Installing pip with correct python version

Tags: python

I am on shared hosting and I need to install pip with the correct python version, 2.7. To install pip, I did:

```
$ easy_install pip
```

However, after it was installed I get the following:

```
[dave@web1 lib]$ pip --version
pip 1.0.2 from /home/premiere/dave/financials/lib/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.4)
```

How would I re-install pip to work on the `python2.7` version, which is also installed on the machine?

```
[premiered@web1 ~]$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Which is strange, since it is installing to python2.4.

Comment: What do you get when you type `python --version`?

Comment: 2.6.6. I added this in the question

Comment: No it DOES NOT installed to python2.4, but correctly 2.7, according to `-py2.7.egg` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a virtualenv using `-p /path/to/python-2.7.binary` param, and then activate it. Then all stuff you installed using `pip` would be correctly into your virtualenv.

Comment: How do I find where my python binary is?

Comment: By default all python binaries are inside `/usr/bin`, such as `/usr/bin/python2.7`. If you are able to run `python2.7` from terminal, you should be able to use `which python2.7` to get its location :)

Answer (score 0):

If multiple versions of python are installed on the system, then you should invoke the version you want when installing.  i.e.

```
$ python27 easy_install pip
```

This creates a pip file in your path that contains the specified version of python in the hashBang line.